# Javascript refresh happening before child form updates the db

Tags: javascript, refresh

My Page is getting refreshed by onClick action before execute method() provided in the form submit, which is actually doing a database update. Could you please help to resolve this?
Below method didn't work.

```
<form onsubmit="if(check()){return execute('category/add.do?<passing_parameters...>');}else{return false;}">   <input type="Submit" value="Add" onclick="javascript:close2();"/>   </form>

<script type="text/javascript">   function close2(){   window.onunload = refreshParent;            function refreshParent() {   window.opener.location.reload();   }   </script>
```

How to make sure my database update action from child window is getting updated first and then parent window is getting refreshed? I want my parent window to show the updates made to db from child window form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...note that I removed the onclick event...you don't need it since onsubmit will be triggered when you click the submit button.

```
<form onsubmit="form_submit()">   <input type="Submit" value="Add" />   </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function form_submit() {
    if(check()) {
        var success = execute('category/add.do?<passing_parameters...>');
        if (success) close2();
        return success;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function close2(){   window.onunload = refreshParent; }
function refreshParent() {   window.opener.location.reload();   }

</script>
```